# Time vs Value plot in android

Tags: java, android, graph, charts

I want to plot a `Time vs Value` graph for my app with `Time` on the `x-axis` and the values on the y-axis for which I am using `ChartView` https://github.com/nadavfima/ChartView. But I am facing problems in inserting `Time`  to the `x-axis` as it accepts only integers. How do I get rid of this issue? I have the time values in the format "dd-MMM-YYYY  h:mm:ss". Tried using `achartengine` but not satisfied with it. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your times into doubles so they can be used by ChartView, and then create your own LabelAdapter to convert those double values back to a time format when the labels are displayed.

For example, you could use code like this to get the time in milliseconds, assuming you've already parsed your input format into year, month, day, etc.

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, hour, min, sec);
double floatTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

For an example how to create a LabelAdpater, have a look at the [example code](https://github.com/nadavfima/ChartView/blob/master/ChartViewExample/src/com/example/chartviewexample/ValueLabelAdapter.java) include with ChartView.

In that example, they're just writing out the label as a float like this:

```
labelTextView.setText(String.format("%.1f", getItem(position)));
```

But you could easily do something like this instead:

```
double floatTime = getItem(position);
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.setTimeInMillis((long)floatTime);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());     
String stringTime = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());

labelTextView.setText(stringTime);
```

Comment: Yeah I tried converting Time to Double and ploted the graph but couldnot change the Label on the x-axis back to time.

Comment: Did you create a LabelAdapter class? Did you call `chartView.setBottomLabelAdapter`? How did it fail? Did you have problems compiling it? Did the `getView` method never get called?